# Multipath identifier "xxx" could not be bound

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a file upload control and an "upload" button in my page. I am trying to write codes for uploading word files to my db.

Please find below the code:-

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {

                string fileextention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                if (fileextention == ".doc" || fileextention == ".docx")
                {
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    //Upload file
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DocumentCollection/")  + filename);
                    string fullpath = "DocumentCollection/" + filename;
                    string query = "insert into dbo.DocumentMaster(Name,Path) values(" + filename + "," + "DocumentCollection/" + filename + ");";
                    SqlDataAdapter objda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, objcon);


                    objcon.Open();
                    objda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    objcon.Close();
                    Label2.Text = " successfully uploaded.";

                }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "Selected File is not a word document file.";
                }
```

My DB structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentMaster](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Path] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

But I am encountering an error when i am trying to upload a word.docx file. The word.docx has been successfully uploaded to the DocumentCollection folder in my application.

*The multi-part identifier "word.docx" could not be bound.
Invalid column name 'DocumentCollection'.
The multi-part identifier "word.docx" could not be bound.*

Please help me.

Comment: Name and Path are varchar - you need to enclose the values in ` (single quotes).  I would also suggest you look into using parameterized queries as a matter of habit, lest you leave yourself open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: In other words, `"insert into dbo.DocumentMaster(Name,Path) values('" + filename + "',"' + "DocumentCollection/" + filename + "');";` - note the single quotes surrounding the values to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially what you're sending to the database:

```
insert into dbo.DocumentMaster(Name,Path) values(word.docx,DocumentCollection/word.docx)
```

As you can see, you're not sending "strings" for the values part.

You may do this:

```
string query = "insert into dbo.DocumentMaster(Name,Path) values('" + filename + "','" + "DocumentCollection/" + filename + "');";
```

So you get this query as a result:

```
insert into dbo.DocumentMaster(Name,Path) values('word.docx','DocumentCollection/word.docx')
```

to fix your problem, but you're still very susceptible to SQL Injection. I highly suggest you use a parameterized query instead.